# Can I change what displays the Launcher is shown on

Tags: unity, launcher, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Duplicate Second Unity Launcher on Dual Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-dual-screen)

In precise, when using a dual screen setting, the Unity launcher is present on both screens:

[image: Dual screen with two launchers]

Is it possible to have it only on the main screen?

Comment: Have you seen this question: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-dual-screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-dual-screen) As a side thought, I believe they are planning to change this default behaviour. See [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/ubuntu-12-04-multi-monitor-to-be/)