# Unity on Both Screens with Dual Monitors

Tags: unity, 12.04, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Duplicate Second Unity Launcher on Dual Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-dual-screen)

After going to `12.04` the unity launcher now appears on both of my screens. I have screens configured as one large desktop, so I only want unity on one of the monitors.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change this in the Displays dialog. Launch Displays (either from System Settings > Displays or by typing Displays in to Dash).

From there select which monitor you'd like Unity to appear on:

[image: Display settings]