# How do I remove the launcher from my second monitor display?

Tags: launcher

My workspace extends, and is not a mirror or copy of original display, but I still get the vertical purple Icon launcher bar on both screens and see no way to remove it. Please advise!

Comment: is it also possible to remove toolbar with clock on top of the screen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can configure whether the launcher will show on all monitors or in a single one:

Open the dash and type `display`

Now configure where you want the launcher to appear:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Even though 12.04 thinks my dual-monitor desktop pc setup is in fact a massive (3200 x 1080) laptop screen.

Comment: That's because, for any practical purpose, it is. As you said yourself, your workspace *extends* (as opposed to clone/mirror or dual-screen), so for any application you *do* have a massive 3200x1800 screen. That's the size of your single workspace.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work with nVidia's TwinView. There is only one screen there ("Laptop") and while selecting it does remove the launcher from one of my displays, it is not the one I want.

Comment: @Timmmm: I am not sure how Nvidia's TwinView works. Is that some sort of "clone" displays, where both show the same content? Anyway, it is a pity Nvidia's software does not play nice with Ubuntu and Linux in general. I use ATI/AMD, and their proprietary control panel (Catalyst) and it shows the same displays and configuration as in Ubuntu's built in tool. Well, NVidia is widely known for being extremely uncooperative with the open software world.

Comment: @MestreLion: It creates a virtual desktop spread over several screens. [According to nVidia](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/304.37/README/configtwinview.html) it has some advantages of Xinerama, e.g. OpenGL across two screens. I have to say, I'm slightly sympathetic to nVidia, given the fact that their drivers are pretty solid, and the Linux graphics stack is a complete mess . It's finally improving with KMS and Wayland, but realistically those are about 10 years late and still not ready.

Comment: nVidia users cheer up and have a look at the accepted answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/107583/64513 Also it seems starting from driver version 3xx nvidia integrates better in the system but I can't verify this at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Nvidia video card you need to run the Nvidia software and change the primary display. Don't know about other chipsets

Comment: But the sticky edges stays on even if you turn them off, which is a bit of a pain!

Answer (score 1):

**It is simple**
Go to Settings --> Dock --> Show on
Select Built-in display
That's it

For more information
[image: .]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the 'Launcher' (which contains the Ubuntu symbol, Home folder, Ubuntu Software Manager, Ubuntu One, etc etc) on the left of the screen? If yes, then follow these instructions:

1. On the desktop, **right-click** and select *Change Desktop Background*.
2. Switch to *Behavior* tab.
3. Change *Auto-hide the Launcher* from OFF to ON.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. This enables autohide of the HUD on both monitors, but I wish to remove the launcher from only my second monitor (and not to hide it, which still interferes with the mouse movement across screens).

Comment: Totally forgot that when we Auto-hide, it hides on both monitors sigh*
sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia users, just disable "Xinerama", restart lightdm and then make changes to Display and Enable Xinerama.

Steps:

1. edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
2. change Xinerama value from 1 to 0
3. service lightdm restart
4. System Settings -> Display -> Launcher placement -> select monitor
5. edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
6. change Xinerama value from 0 to 1
7. service lightdm restart

You can disable sticky edge this way too.