# How can I stop the Unity bar from causing cursor delay between two monitors?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

If I have two monitors, side by side, then the Unity bar will interfere with mouse movement. I set the unity bar to only display if I move the mouse to the top left corner of the screen, but the mouse still pauses momentarily when I move the mouse from the right display to the left display. The place it pauses, is exactly on the left border of the right screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have sticky borders enabled. Remove the option sticky borders.

[image]

A similar problem has been answered here: [How do I disable mouse magnet on middle edge with multi monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109338/how-do-i-disable-mouse-magnet-on-middle-edge-with-multi-monitors)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Ah, there is still a small delay the, to give unity the option to come out of autohide, but the pain is gone!

Answer (score 1):

Another post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-dual-screen) will help, and provide you with some options to set things up the way you want.