# How can I remove third Unity Launcher on a 3+ Screen setup?

Tags: unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, launcher

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-a-dual-screen-setup), we learn how to select ONE display to show the Unity launcher on in a 2-screen setup.

My question is: How can we use the Unity launcher in MULTIPLE displays, but not all of them?

For example, the following shows three screens with the launcher enabled on all of them:

> [image: 3 Screens with Unity launcher enabled on all]

The only GUI setting I can use to modify this is "Launcher placement" but only allows selecting ONE display:

> [image: 3 Screens with Unity launcher enabled on bottom]

The end result I'm looking for is to turn OFF the launcher on the vertical (right-hand) screen, but keep them on the left-hand screens.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to configure the launcher in this manner.

Comment: @Nathan: It's not because you don't like the answer that it's not valid...  It is! (and that's why I upvoted) so don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the abysmally small number at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)