# Show Application on Window Where Opened with Unity Launcher

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, launcher

I figured I'd be able to find someone with a similar post as mine - maybe I'm using the wrong search criteria.

That said, I have three monitors. I have the launcher enabled on all three monitors. It essentially duplicates all of my applications pinned and opened on each monitor. I'd like to configure it so that open applications only show up on the display they are opened in. I.e., if VS Codium is open in my left monitor, the icon would appear on that launcher, not the one on my main or third display.

Any insight is appreciated!

Edit: Apologies for not mentioning: I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/107583/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-second-unity-launcher-on-a-dual-screen-setup?noredirect=1&lq=1